# Average data frames with common characters in their name in a list in R

Tags: r

I have several .csv files from different experiments some of which are repeats of the same experiment and therefore need to be averaged. The files are of the type:

A_a.csv, A_b.csv, A_c.csv; B_a.csv, B_c.csv; C_a.csv, C_b.csv, C_c.csv, C_d.csv etc

where A, B, C,... refer to different experiments while a, b, c,... refer to repeats of the same experiment. Each csv file contains a Time column and an Abs column.

I have created a list of data frames from all those files and i want to get a list where the repeats are averaged so the output will be a list like:

A.csv, B.csv, C.csv,...

where A, B, C,... are data frames with Time and Abs being the row average of the Time and Abs of each repeat experiment. Below i attach a simplified example where Li is the initial list and Lf the desired output:

`Li<- list(A_a=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=1:5),A_b=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=3:7),A_c=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=5:9),B_a=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=2:6),B_b=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=3:7))`

```
Lf<-list(A=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=3:7),B=data.frame(Time=1:5,Abs=seq(2.5,6.5,1)))
```

I think that i need to get R to look for the data frames in the list that have the same first x characters in their name, isolate those data frames, average appropriately and then generate a dataframe with that name and without the repeat experiment extension (in our example these are the lower case letters after the _) but i dont know how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` you could row bind you list into a single `data.table` and then do aggregation per group.

```
library(data.table)
out <- rbindlist(Li, idcol = "id")[, .(Abs = mean(Abs)), by = .(id = substring(id, 1, 1), Time)]
out
#    id Time Abs
# 1:  A    1 3.0
# 2:  A    2 4.0
# 3:  A    3 5.0
# 4:  A    4 6.0
# 5:  A    5 7.0
# 6:  B    1 2.5
# 7:  B    2 3.5
# 8:  B    3 4.5
# 9:  B    4 5.5
#10:  B    5 6.5
```

As you see, this results in a single `data.table`. Use `split(out, out[, id])` if you need a list.

Comment: so clean, I love it